# Mac Firebreath plugin port to Linux dependencies

Tags: linux, macos, opengl, core-audio, firebreath

I have Firebreath plugin for Mac that I need to port to Linux

I am trying to find the replacement dependencies for the Linux version. Here is the dependencies I have in my `cmake` for Mac:

```
find_library(COCOA_F Cocoa) 
find_library(FOUNDATION_F Foundation) 
find_library(APPKIT_F AppKit) 
find_library(COREDATA_F CoreData) 
find_library(AGL_F AGL) 
find_library(CARBON_F Carbon) 
find_library(AUDIOTOOLBOX_F AudioToolbox) 
find_library(COREAUDIO_F CoreAudio) 
find_library(AUDIOUNIT_F AudioUnit) 
find_library(QUARTZCORE_F QuartzCore) 
find_library(QUICKTIME_F QuickTime) 
find_library(OPENGL_F OpenGL) 
find_library(QTKIT_F QTKit)
```

So far,

```
OpenGL       => freeglut3 ?
Cocoa        => GLFW ?
```

any suggestions for the other dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that there are many direct replacements for these.  Rather than looking for direct replacements for each library, figure out what functionality you need and find libraries that provide it.

For example, Carbon covers so many different types of things that it's impossible to guess what libraries on linux you'd actually need.  CoreAudio is a little more clear, as it deals with sound, but are you doing sound playback or some other type of sound manipulation?

Better to look for libraries that provide the functionality you need.  For example, for sound playback you'll likely want alsa.  OpenCV or video4linux both give you webcam access, etc.

Once you have broken it down to what *functionality* you need a bit of google searching will almost certainly answer your questions without needing to rely on outside help and you can save your questions for specific problems you may run into while doing the port.